# Automatic and manual text wrapping in Java

Tags: java, text, word-wrap

I need as the title says to wrap a text (a String) in Java in both, automatic and manual mode. For automatic mode I use the "word-wrap" library that wrap the text with a max-length characters, but I need also to add a manual mode, like for example with the key "/". Can someone help me please?

I have tried to have a String like "this is an example string/I need to wrap" and also if I use a for loop to split the strings the word wrap, that is executed before. This is an example:

```
That is an example I need to fix /a example test.
```

Say the manual wrap key is "/" and the max characters are 35. The result will be:

```
That is an example I need to fix
a example test.
```

But here how is it:

```
That is an example I need to fix
a
example test
```

Comment: The obvious thing that springs to mind is to embed an escaped newline character, e.g. `"That is an example I need to fix \\na example test."` Then do a replace with an *actual* newline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that demonstrates what you want.

```
public static final String wrap(String toWrap, String wrapKey, int maxLineLength) {
    String string = new String();
    String[] words = toWrap.split(" ");

    int currentLineLength = 0;
    for (String word : words) {

        // Manual warping
        if(word.contains(wrapKey)) {
            while(word.contains(wrapKey)) 
                word = word.replaceFirst(wrapKey, "\n");
            
            string += (word + " ");
            currentLineLength = 0;
                
            continue; // Avoid auto-wrapping
        }
        // Auto warping
        if(currentLineLength + word.length() + 1 <= maxLineLength) {
            string += (word + " ");
            currentLineLength += word.length() + 1;
        }
        else {
            string += ("\n" + word + " ");
            currentLineLength = word.length() + 1;
        }
    }

    return string.trim();
}
```

And using it like so

```
String example = "That is an example I need to fix /a example test.";
        
System.out.println(wrap(example, "/", 35));
```

You should get

```
That is an example I need to fix 
a example test.
```

---

Alternatively your could use the ApacheCommon's [`WordUtils#wrap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#wrap(java.lang.String,int)) method

Comment: Thank your for your reply, yes I know there aren't any bugs in my or in your code but I'm searching for a code that will give me that output like:

"That is an example I need to fix
a example test. " as I said in my first question where there is "The result will be:"

Comment: @alexmens I found a mistake in my code, I didn't reset the line length, sorry. Please check the updated version.